# have removed rubygems.org source, still using it

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have removed the http://rubygems.org source with gem sources -r http://rubygems.org. But when I run helios new sample, it is still using rubygems.org source, not the ruby.taobao.org source I added. How to set the helios command to use this only available gem source to install other gems?

Comment: checked your Gemfile?

Comment: Yeah, I just checked. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just break the execution of helios new, and modify the Gemfile and replace the source with new source. It's installing fast now.